# Как указать количество кликов мышкой?

Tags: python

В общем, пытаюсь сделать клик мышкой, вроде всё отлично но до момента, где не работает clicks, когда я указываю сколько кликов хочу(/ms 1-2-3 и тд). Прошу помощи )

```
@botik.message_handler(commands=['MS'])
def ClickLeft(message):
    try:
        botik.reply_to(message, '*Нажимаю...*', parse_mode="Markdown")
        user_msg = "{0}".format(message.text)
        time.sleep( 1.8 )
        cl , viborclick = user_msg.split(" ")[1]
        pidarsmouse.click(clicks = cl, button = viborclick )
        # Screen
        screenss()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Сори за вставку кода, не знаю как вставить так, чтобы было ровно)
Вот скрин кода  - https://imgur.com/a/C1YkjRb

Comment: Так вы вызываете не пойми что с не очень корректным названием. Мы должны догадаться, что это вообще? И какой у вас формат сообщения, который вы разбираете - тоже нужно догадаться?